# np.where: "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"

Tags: python

I am trying to incorporate the following logic

In Column A, where column B = Stack then Column A * 100 otherwise keep column A as-is.

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['columnB'] = 'Stack', df['Value'] * 100)
```

why am I getting a `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` here?

Comment: I see one error.  `df['columnB'] = 'Stack'` should be `df['columnB'] == 'Stack'`

Comment: damn, i see it now. my mistake.. should i just delete this then?

Comment: Depends if you think others will encounter this problem and might find this useful.  But it is rather trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply a condition and two outcomes for the binary condition

Without knowing much about you `dataframe` I believe you should be doing something like the following:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['columnB'] == 'Stack', df['columnA']*100, df['Value'])
```

This is because in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) it states:

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
    Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.

Parameters: 
    condition : array_like, bool
    Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y.
```

So `df['Value']` would be populated with `columnA` times 100 if `columnB` is `'Stack'`, otherwise, it keeps the value that is stored at `Value`